# Use read_table to read a file with quoted header names in tidyverse

Tags: r, tidyverse, read.table

I have a file with this format

```
     "date" "obs"
2010060101 0.015
2010060102 0.015
```

I can read it with

```
read.table("filehour.txt", header=TRUE)
```

To get:

```
        date   obs  
1 2010060101 0.015
2 2010060102 0.015
3 2010060103 0.015
```

And I get a data.frame with the column names unquoted which is what I want so it works ok. But when I try to use the tidyverse style with `read_table` to return a tibble instead of a data.frame like so:

```
read_table2("filehour.txt")
```

I get

```
-- Column specification -----------------------------------------------
cols(
  `"date"` = col_double(),
  `"obs"` = col_double()
)
```

with the header names quoted which I don't want because then I would have to reference them as

```
`"date"` 
`"obs"`
```

I could name the column names with read_table parameter `col.names` but isn't `read_table2` the equivalent to `read.table` or is there any other function or parameter to get the same results without having to explicitly name the columns using the tidyverse package?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `read_delim` which has `quote` argument which is absent in `read_table`.

```
readr::read_delim("filehour.txt", ' ')
```

Comment: Yes it works with readr::read_delim and it seems it's the only function in tidyverse were you can use quotes